# Comparing Times In PHP Using MySQL Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have activity logs stored in my mysql database, each with a registered datetime. I am trying to write a short php script to delete all logs that are older than 60 days. I am having trouble trying to compare the times in datetime format.

Here's what I have:

```
$sixty_days_past = strtotime("-60 days");

$earliest_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $sixty_days_past);

$logs_result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM df_logs WHERE date < '$earliest_time'");

    while($logs_row = mysql_fetch_array($logs_result)) { 

        $oldentry = $logs_row['id'];

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM df_logs WHERE id='$oldentry'");    

    }
```

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything.

```
DELETE FROM `df_logs` WHERE `date` < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -60 DAY)
```

Done.

---

To elaborate:

- You are going through PHP when MySQL is perfectly capable of doing the right calculations
- You are not enclosing field names in backticks, which is a problem because `date` is a keyword.
- You are deleting rows one at a time, which results in a potentially unbound number of queries, instead of deleting them all at once (such as with `IN` to list the IDs to delete)